# In storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion in kmeans

Tags: r, data-mining

I am trying to split my data into 5 clusters. But I am getting the following error

```
> colSums(sapply(train1,is.na))
     train_id              name item_condition_id     category_name 
            0                 0                 0                 0 
   brand_name             price          shipping  item_description 
            0                 0                 0                 0 
> train1matrix=as.matrix(train1)
> train1vector=as.vector(train1matrix)
> k=5
> set.seed(88)
> KMC=kmeans(train1vector,centers=k,iter.max=1000)
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Can someone please help me?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please use `fput` to share data in `train1`.

Comment: Thank you... But I am yet to try..do you mean to tell that to copy data from old data frame to new dataframe, I shud use fput?

Comment: You should share the output of `dput(train1)` or, at least `dput(train1[1:20,])`

Answer (score 5):

kmeans *can* only be used on numerical columns, because it needs to compute the *mean*.

Don't use it on "ID" columns, text columns etc. where it does not make sense to compute the *mean*. It appears that you are trying to run kmeans on such 'bad' columns.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work for date-time datatype(POSIXct) also. I was facing issue because of date-time column.
It works only for numeric and integer data-types.

You can check for data-types of columns/features using below,

- **View(sapply(dataframeName, class))**