# issues with creating k-means clusters in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to make the data into 3 clusters but I run into this error in my code:

```
#Compute k-means with k=3
library(ggplot2)
library(cluster)
library(factoextra)
library(tidyverse)
library(FactoMineR)

set.seed(123)
protein2 <- read_csv("Downloads/protein.csv")
k1<- kmeans(protein2, centers=3, nstart=25)
print(k1)
```

the error appears for my k-means function in R. I dont know how to fix it.
I will attach my data set:

[image: dataframe]

Comment: Please give a sample of your data using `dput`, just giving the screenshot of your data is not helpful : ) and also attach the error message you are having with your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the problem is related to the inclusion of the first column (Countries), which is made by strings, in the computation of the kmeans clustering (as reported in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48021274/in-storage-modex-double-nas-introduced-by-coercion-in-kmeans)).

replacing the line in which you create k1 with:

```
k1<- kmeans(protein2[, 2:3], centers=3, nstart=25)
```

should solve the issue in your case.